# A pdf file can not be show in Abobe Reader

Tags: pdf

I have generated a pdf file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8u9ruy6nv78tnd/Can_not_show_in_Adobe_Reader.pdf ,
It's page is very wide--752.69 Inch. It can't be show in Adobe Reader--just two blank page, but it can be show in Chrome and FireFox browser with their default pdf viewer.

I want to know why it can't be show in Adobe Reader. Could someone give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Appendix C of http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf as it clearly states that:

```
177. In PDF versions earlier than PDF 1.6, the size of the default user space unit is fixed at 1 / 72 inch. In 
Acrobat viewers earlier than version 4.0, the minimum allowed page size is 72 by 72 units in default 
user space (1 by 1 inch); the maximum is 3240 by 3240 units (45 by 45 inches). In Acrobat versions 5.0 
and later, the minimum allowed page size is 3 by 3 units (approximately 0.04 by 0.04 inch); the 
maximum is 14,400 by 14,400 units (200 by 200 inches). 

Beginning with PDF 1.6, the size of the default user space unit may be set with the UserUnit entry of 
the page dictionary. Acrobat 7.0 supports a maximum UserUnit value of 75,000, which gives a 
maximum page dimension of 15,000,000 inches (14,400 * 75,000 * 1 / 72). The minimum UserUnit 
value is 1.0 (the default).
```